# Jquery iterating with map set two div elements in the same loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting a json value through an ajax call and I am iterating over it to set contents of table and a div using two separate methods, how can i combine both the functions into a single one as i am iterating through the same data

```
function render_table(json_value){

    $("tbody").append(
        $.map(json_value['comments'], function(event, idx) {

            return (
                `<tr ">
                    <td></td>
                </tr>`
            );

        }).join());
}

function render_list(json_value){

    $(".history ul").append(

        $.map(json_value['comments'], function(event, idx){

            return (`
                    <li> 
                        <div >

                        </div>
                    </li>`
                );

        }).join(' '));

}
```

Comment: `details['comments']`?

Comment: sorry changed json_value['comments']

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function render(json_value) {
  $.each(json_value['comments'], function(index, value) {
    $("tbody").append(`<tr><td></td></tr>`);
    $(".history ul").append(`<li><div></div></li>`);
  });
}
```

Comment: yes thats what i am doing in separate, sorry i edited question, i am using json_value['comments'] in both map calls (same values), so how can i combine into single one ?

Comment: Not getting what you exactly mean here. can you post the code structure about what you are looking for as a combined single function?

Comment: sure actually i thought of implementing both the table data and history data while iterating through single loop 
eg: function render(json_value){
   
// iterate through map and set value for both $("tbody").append() and $(".history ul").append()
}

Comment: Yup that works fine, but i thought using map do it but i think its not possible to use map in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Even better:

```
function render(json_value){
    // cache jQuery DOM elements for better performance 
    var $tbody = $("tbody"),
        $historyList = $(".history ul");

    // split code functionality into stand-alone pieces which eahc do its own thing 
    json_value['comments'].forEach(function(index, value){
        addTableRow(value);
        addListItem(value);
    });

    function addTableRow( data ){
        var template = `<tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>${data}</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`;

        $tbody.append(template);
    }

    function addListItem( data ){
        var template = `<li>
                            <div>${data}</div>
                        </li>`;

        $historyList.append(template);
    }
}
```

This is only one possible way to order the code so it would be more manageable. There are many design-patters and you should choose the one which will be the most robust for your specific need.

Comment: Thanks mate, this works !! but we cannot use two callbacks in map right ?? also can i know whether its good to have html in $tbody.append() as i have tr with 3 <td> and each <td> has 2 <p> in it. If i add everything in same template literal its not manageble i think is there any other good solution for it

Comment: @RinsenS - yes there is a better way! I will edit my answer to improve the on the template area (updated now)